# Android Show video on home screen like skype after minimizing app

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

How is Skype managing to show video call drag able pop up on home screen after minimizing Skype app during call. You can select and start other application from home screen and Skype popup is still on screen even parallel with other application. If it is App widget then how do I add or remove on home screen and in top of other application UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use WindowManager to add a Float view:

```
private void createFloatView()
{
    Button btn_floatView = new Button();
    btn_floatView = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn_floatView.setText("FloatView");

    wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    params.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;

    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;

    params.width = 100;
    params.height = 100;

    btn_floatView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        int lastX, lastY;
        int paramX, paramY;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastX = (int) event.getRawX();
                lastY = (int) event.getRawY();
                paramX = params.x;
                paramY = params.y;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int dx = (int) event.getRawX() - lastX;
                int dy = (int) event.getRawY() - lastY;
                params.x = paramX + dx;
                params.y = paramY + dy;
                wm.updateViewLayout(btn_floatView, params);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    wm.addView(btn_floatView, params);
    isAdded = true;
}
```